# Set Opera context menu quick search to open new tab

Tags: tabs, opera

How can I make Opera open a new tab and set focus on it when using the context menu quick search? Currently it loads the quick search in the same tab. I can manually hold Shift or Ctrl to open a new tab when loading a quick search but I don't want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Settings -> Preferences... -> Advanced -> Tabs -> Reuse current tab